# How to Track "button clicks" in react js android application via Firebase?

Tags: java, reactjs, firebase, react-native, android-studio

I am new in dealing with react native apps and I am trying to find out how to track few buttons that is being available on my android application.

In my react native app, there is a "submit" button while signing up into the app and I want to track that button via Firebase, but have no idea on how to do that in android studio project for an react native application. Although I know the similar code which I need to put but not sure how to identify the button class element right here.

Here's the similar code what I need to put:

```
``
  Button b1= findViewById(R.id.button2);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("Button_text","Sign_up");
                    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("Sign_up_button",bundle);
            }
``
```

[This is my react native app, and I don't know where is the right button I am trying to find out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRdr4.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by tracking a button via Firebase?

Comment: I am using Firebase analytics for tracking events in my app which is build upon react js. So, I want to track custom events but don't know which code or script I add into the applicaton to track these events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RNFirebase](https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/usage) should be integrated into the react-native project.

As explained in the document the event tracking for the button action should be handled in `onPress` callback method

```
import react, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';

function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title="Add To Basket"
        onPress={async () =>
          await analytics().logEvent('Event Name', {
            Data Object
          })
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Vignesh, for providing the solution, I hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Vignesh, for providing the solution, I hope it will work. But just one more question, into which file and at which place in android studio project, I need to add this event script to successfully track these events?

Comment: @Learner You have all the Android native code inside the folder `android` and react native code inside the folder `src`, based on the screenshot attached by you I guess you need to update the code in file `PaymentTransactionUpload.js` instead of guessing I suggest you to [debug](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging) this code.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Vignesh, I really appreciate your time and effort for providing this solution.